# How to connect FortiGate1 SSL VPN remote access from Fedora/CentOS/Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, fedora, centos

How can i connect to FortiGate1 SSL VPN Remote Access router from Fedora/CentOS or Ubuntu/Debian?

It only working with Windows Internet explorer for the moment using Vbox (But i cant use Windows only for this)

How can i use it from my favourate Linux?

```
# vpnc
Enter IPSec gateway address: xx.xx.xx.42
Enter IPSec ID for xx.xx.xx.42: 
Enter IPSec secret for @xx.xx.xx.42: 
Enter username for xx.xx.xx.42: Myusername
Enter password for Myusername@xxxxx.42: 
vpnc: no response from target
```

Comment: You can always try setting up a generic VPN connection with your FortiGate info in the Ubuntu Network utility (which may exist in other flavors). I've had some success doing that before. Depends on what FortiGate really implements (and how's it's configured)..

Comment: @Doc: Plz see above failed. (Basically in Windows internet explorer i put username/password, click SSL VPN and it just create a connection, then i have a new ip). But in Linux i cant find out anything to connect this straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an official client provided by Fortigate for use with linux called "forticlient ssl vpn linux".

You can download the client from the [fortigate support site](https://support.fortinet.com/). However it requires an account to access. Your network admins can probably get it for you.
Alternatively, if you just google for "forticlientsslvpn linux", there are several results on the first page that have a download available.

Answer (score 1):

**Not solved**

It is not possible to use Fortigate1 ssl vpn router in Linux. Because it has nothing for Linux, its completely designed for Windows and Internet explorer ActiveX. So the best solution is VirtualBox with Windows XP and use the Internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I am bumping an old thread, since I was recently found about this too. It is all running in CLI by the way

You can [Download Fortigate SSLVPN CLI](http://cdn.software-mirrors.com/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.4.2328.tar.gz) and extract it to any folder then navigate to to `forticlientsslvpn/64bit/` or `forticlientsslvpn/32bit/`

after that just run: `./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server serveraddress:port --vpnuser username`

And you are done.

Source: https://www.networkreverse.com/2020/09/setup-linux-router-with-forticlient.html